# Why data in my array is not being evaluated properly?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here in this loop it is not entering into second and third if statements even though condition is  satisfying!

Basically what I wanted is to find the name of the person based on their information, I have created array and in that there will be corresponding roll numbers and pin and their name,
I am taking input using text field and storing it in another array named para, now when I try to get information from that array it is not giving proper output like
for inputs
n
3
1
it has to give an output nandini but it is not happening.

even though arr[0][1] is equal to 3 it is not entering into if statement. I also tried '$para[]' instead of para[] but still I am not able to get expected output..

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
      
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
           
            primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(
              title:
                  '                                                                                           HELLO AM SRUJITH CHAITHANYA'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    TextEditingController _next = TextEditingController();
    
    var arr = [
      [ 
        //roll numbers
        1,
        3,
        8,
        1,
        8
      ],
      [
        //pin
        0,
        1,
        2,
        4,
        2
    
      ],
      [
        //name
        'Srujith',
        'nandini',
        'pratheek',
        'rachana',
        'avani'
      ],
    ];
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
      
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    var para = [];
    var i = 0;
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      var qi = 0;
      var change;
      var operator;
      var operato;
      var result;
      var fname;
      var f;
      void answer() {
        setState(() {
          qi = qi + 1;
          i = i + 1;
          change = _next.text;
          operator = change;
          para.add(operator);
          _next.text = '';
          
          setState(() {});
        });
        if(i==3){
       for(int o=0;o<5;o++){
         f = arr[2][o];
          fname = f.substring(0, 1);
           if(para[0]==fname){
             result = 'named';
             if(para[1]==arr[0][o]){
               result = 'rolled';
               if(para[2]==arr[1][o]){
    
                 result = arr[2][o];
                 break;
               }
             }
           }
       }
        }
    
    
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       
        var questions = [
         
          'What is the first letter of your name?',
          'What is your roll number?',
          'What is your pin?',
          'question 4'
        
        ];
        return Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: null,
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            
            title: Text(widget.title),
            elevation: 0,
          ),
          body: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.5ffeb9b88264485f1b265ff3c94e2dc2?rik=q1VHggJH5dpvmQ&riu=http%3a%2f%2fthewowstyle.com%2fwp-content%2fuploads%2f2015%2f01%2fnature-image.jpg&ehk=1zrBUw2Jkcik7R719ZPnOjG8MrGPNepNGF1KdErFfw4%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            child: Center(
              
              child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                
                  Text(
                    questions[qi],
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
    
                  Container(
                    width: 0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _next,
                       // keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
    
                  Text(
                    ('$result'),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    ('$i'),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
                  
                  Text(
                    ('$para'),
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('answer'),
                    onPressed: answer,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: please add clean code or comments so we can understand

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try using if-else-if instead of single if statements:

```
for(int o=0;o<5;o++){
     f = arr[2][o];
      fname = f.substring(0, 1);
       if(para[0]==fname)
         result = 'named';
        else if(para[1]==arr[0][o])
         result = 'rolled';
        else if(para[2]==arr[1][o])
         result = arr[2][o];
        else 
         return 0; 
}
```

ps: it might also be because you didn't add correct { }

Comment: No... I want to satisfy all three if statements I just added 'named' and 'rolled' just to ensure if it is going inside the if statement